# Как через цикл найти сумму значений, которые подходят под условие?

Tags: r

Пишу код. Но вместо подсчета суммы всех значений, которые подошли, просто выдаёт последнее подходящее значение. Как сохранить *все* подходящие под условие значения?

```
filtered.sum <- function(x){
  x[is.na(x)] <- 0
  d <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    if (x[i]>0){
      s <- x[i]
    }
  } 
  d <- d+s
  return(d)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, что `d <- d+s` нужно перенести под if. А так в `s` каждый раз записывается новое значение - и после выхода из цикла там, конечно же, лежит последнее значение.

Comment: я этот ваш язык впервые вижу, но странно, почему не `d <- d+x[i]` ?

Comment: @Zufir спасибо! Я был близок...

Answer (score 7):

Этот код можно заменить двумя строчками:

```
x[is.na(x)] <- 0
sum(x[x >= 0])
```

Comment: Да Вы правы, просто хотел понять, как это сделать с for+if

Comment: Всё же правильнее сделать это в одну строку (так как в этом случае не происходит изменения входных данных): `sum(x[x >= 0], na.rm = TRUE)`, но если делать точное соответствие решению из условия, то да.

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант
 cumsum(na.omit(x))